# Experience Editor is not showing the ribbon options in sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, keystone

I have logged in to sitecore through administrator account. I have a page in my site if press 'experience editor' or preview button,editor ribbon is not displaying. I am new to sitecore, Is that a permission issue am facing?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the Sitecore logs?

Answer (score 4):

If you see only header of the ribbon like that: [image]

Click on the arrow on the right. You should see all the options:

[image]

If you don't see even the header, there must be some errors on the console.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  even the header is not displayed, and also no error's in browser console.

Comment: You're using administrator account so it's not access right issue. Is there anything in the source of your page? You `<body>` should start with `<form id='scPageExtendersForm' `. What browser you use? Can you try private mode in another browser?

Comment: Two pages i have. Default sitecore  page is starting with  <form id='scPageExtendersForm tag and the page which i have created is not having any form tag. Could you please tell me what am missing here. am using chrome browser .In both pages am not getting editor ribbon

Comment: You need to add more information what are the differences between the default Sitecore page you have and the other one

Answer (score 0):

This specifically applies to MVC implementations and could apply to Webforms as well.  Please make sure your layout razor cshtml file has valid HTML markup skeleton in place.  Please make sure at the very minimum your page is formatted like this:

```
@using Sitecore.MVC

<html>
    <body>
         @Html.Sitecore().Etc...
         etc...
    </body>
</html>
```

This should eliminate the big chunk of JSON on top and enable all page editor UI elements.