# Sitecore Glassmapper Fields not editable

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, glass-mapper, viewrendering

Hi I am new to glassmapper and i am trying to create a simple view rendering. 
While the view works, i am not able to edit it in experience editor. Is  there like a setting that i should turn on???

My View is as simple is this:

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<sample.Web.Models.sampleclass>
@if (Model != null)
{
    <div>
      @Editable(Model,x=>x.Title)
    </div>
}
```

My Modal:

```
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes;
using System;

namespace Sampple.Web.Models.Sampleclass
{
    [SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{FE05DA0F-7E18-47F8-AB77-F0ED7A0F9F90}",AutoMap = true)]
    public class Sampleclass
    {

        [SitecoreId]
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string Title{ get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("Page Content")]
        public virtual string Body{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

I am able to see the content.  It just that it is not editable when i open

```
http://mysite/?sc_mode=edit
```

Sidenote: i have changed the class names for explanation. Please ignore any typos

Comment: Can you add the code for your **sample.Web.Models.sampleclass** class?

Comment: @Barbosa - Done

Comment: did you debug your code? can you see if Model is null ?

Comment: What version of glass are you using?

Comment: @Barbosa - i am using version 4.2

Comment: @sitecoreclimber - My model is not null, that is why i am able to see the content. where i have "Model.Title".  it is just not editable.

Comment: Can you try rendering your **Body** property and seeing if that property is editable?

Comment: could you check permissions for the item and the account you logging on?

Comment: Make sure the **Editing** field is checked from the `View`ribbon: http://imgur.com/a/aepD5

Comment: @jammykam - interestingly i don't see that chunk at all.  http://imgur.com/a/rDJQA

Comment: That looks like a screenshot of the ribbon in Content Editor. Make sure you check when in Experience Editor mode.

Answer (score 0):

I this fixed?

If not, try below options:

- When you open Sitecore Item in Experience Editor and when clicked on any field you must see those fields highlighted as in below screen shots, Then try to edit it within that highlighted area

[Screen Shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXwlW.png)

[Screen Shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJvgi.png)

- if you are at the right place and if it is till not working. Can you check Sitecore Logs if there are any errors recorded.
- Looking at the code it looks like you missed to map "Title" field.

Comment: unfortunately.. not yet.. Weirdly i am not seeing the ribbon at all under experience editor. There are no errors in data logs or in browser.  I can see the ribbon under preview mode though.. http://imgur.com/a/im3IV

Comment: Also i did not have to map the title because it was the same field name. The web works. i am able to see the values. Just editing doesnt work.

Comment: @kveey Is the content within <body> wrapped within <form> tag, Something like this <body id="mainbody" runat="server">
    <form method="post" runat="server" id="mainform"> ... </form></body>.

Also refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541265/experience-editor-is-not-showing-the-ribbon-options-in-sitecore-8